# Combining Shiny app and Rmd file

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I have a RMD file in R and I use shiny app within this file to read csv file and do some cleaning on the data. Then I need to have access to this data in the Rmd file and only after finishing the cleaning, the remaining of Rmd is processed!

My Rmd:

````
---
title: "Report_HTML"
author: "Mohammad"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

## Read file
This report...... (some text)

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(tcltk)
inputPanel(
  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', FALSE),
  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
               c(Comma=',',
                 Semicolon=';',
                 Tab='\t'),
               ';'),
  radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
               c(None='',
                 'Double Quote'='"',
                 'Single Quote'="'"),
               '"'),
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose a file to upload',
            accept = c(
              'text/csv',
              'text/comma-separated-values',
              'text/tab-separated-values',
              'text/plain',
              '.csv',
              '.tsv'
            )
  )
)

remove.duplicates <- function(dt){
   #some data cleaning
   return(dt)
}

datasetInput <- reactive({

  inFile <- input$file1

  dt <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)

  #Remove duplicates
  dt2 <- remove.duplicates(dt)

  dt2

})

renderDataTable({
  datasetInput()
})
```

## Statistics
in this section I need to add some simple statistics like min, max, mean for each column of the `dt`.
```{r, echo=FALSE}
code for calculating min, max, and mean each column dt and show them in a table
```
````

I have two problems:

1. I only want to run the code related to the Statistics section after
   reading and cleaning the data NOT the beginning of loading the Rmd
   file.
2. I don't have access to the `dt` in the Statistics section, how
   can I have access?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a method which is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472001/call-a-rmarkdown-report-in-the-shiny-application/36476563#36476563). I hope that it helps people who have the same problem.