# Call a Rmarkdown report in the shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a shiny application that read a csv file and clean the data and add few columns, ... (I used [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html) to create the app). At the end the application save the cleaned data (*output.csv*) in the *log* folder within the application folder.

I also design a Rmd file which is in the shiny application folder. The Rmd file uses the output file (*log/output.csv*).

I would like to call the Rmd file to show the report after saving the (*output.csv*), How can I do it?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution as follow. Just include the following code lines in your application:

**uo.R:**

```
mainPanel(
      uiOutput("report")
    )
```

**server.R:**

```
output$report <- renderUI({
    includeMarkdown("Report1.Rmd")
  })
```